# How do I remove .0 from Float

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Here is the code:

```
 private fun setData(playerData: TreeMap<String, String>) {
    val values = ArrayList<Entry>()
    val graphData = java.util.ArrayList<Float>()
    for (value in playerData.values) {
        graphData.add(value.toInt().toFloat()) # <-- converting here
    }
    graphData.reverse()

    for (i in 0 until graphData.size) {

        val itemi = i.toFloat()
        values.add(
            Entry(
                itemi, #<-- entering here directly
                graphData[i],
                resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cricket)
            )
        )
    }

    val set1: LineDataSet
    set1 = LineDataSet(values, "Player Form Graph")
    val dataSets = ArrayList<ILineDataSet>()
   // Possible Solution?
    val valueFormatter = IValueFormatter { value, _, _, _ ->
        value.toInt().toString()
    }
    set1.valueFormatter = valueFormatter as ValueFormatter?
    dataSets.add(set1)
    val data = LineData(dataSets)
 // set data
    binding.chart1.data = data

}
```

Error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: <id>DemoFragment$setData$valueFormatter$1 cannot be cast to com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.ValueFormatter`

The thing is some values are working without .0 and some are with .0

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what I have used:

```
set1.valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
            override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
                return value.toInt().toString()
            }
        }
```

In case if there is a chance of value coming in decimal as well, say `[1, 1.2, 3, 3.5]` is your set, then go for:

```
set1.valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
            override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
                return DecimalFormat("#.#").format(value)
            }
        }
```

in above case `#.#` can be replaced with `#.##` if you want to show UPTO 2 decimal places and so on.

Comment: Any insight on this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58412330/charting-set-the-graph-gridlines-fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat( "0" );
```

Comment: how do I use this in my case? where do I work it with the float values?

Comment: use it like  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat( "0" );  TextView.setText(df.format( value));

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!